# How can I assert that a new tab with pdf was opened?

Tags: php, pdf, phpunit, behat, mink

I'm using Behat and Mink to test an application and I have this function:

```
/**
 * @Then é gerado o PDF do cupom selecionado
 */
public function eGeradoOPdfDoCupomSelecionado()
{
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $windowNames = $session->getWindowNames();
    if (sizeof($windowNames) < 2) {
        throw new \ErrorException("2 Janelas deveriam estar abertas");
    }
    //You can even switch to that window
    $session->switchToWindow($windowNames[1]);
}
```

I want to assert that the new tab have a pdf file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the url contains `.pdf` and if you know the name of the file also check that, additionally you see what libraries are available for reading the file and add a check for the content of the file.